# Wordpress one pager anchors and single pages

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm using this theme called Tharsis (one pager). I have little problem between anchors and single pages.

Currently I have 5 links in navigation bar, they are "Palvelut", "Referenssit", "Historia", "Blog", "Ota Yhteyttä". First 3 and last one uses anchors (ex. #palvelut), blog is category.

When I click "Blog" category link from navigation bar, url changes to "site.com/category/blog/."

Now if I click "Palvelut" link then url changes to "site.com/category/blog/#palvelut and that does not take me anywhere.

Here is website I've been working on: http://www.parannapalvelua.fi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using WordPress menus  in that primary menus check out the "Palvelut" and set out  the link which you want. 
[image]

or if you are using html anchor tad then use like this

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/{your path}">Palvelut</a>
```

Comment: Okay I've done that. Now I just face another problem. When using page setting it orders, but when I am using your settings (suggestion) then they change order.

Comment: First it was 1 2 3 now it's 3 2 1

Comment: Lots of laughs...Links are ordered by its date and time. Newest creation will be displayed top. I used quick edit and change that my first created page were created lastly...

Comment: you can remove the order by date option then it will be appears in front as they set in back end Thanks

Comment: Where could I find that?

Comment: may be in your coding side if you applied the  orderby. Make sure use always http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu for using the back end menus this link helps you how retrieve the back end menus

Answer (score 0):

You should put the whole URL in the menu link, followed by the anchor.

Otherwise the link tag interprets always the window active URL as the destination URL, and tries to find an anchor within the current document, which in your case leaves everything unchanged as the active url `/blog` doesnt contain the anchor you are looking for.

Comment: I think in a WordPress menu you can add **whatever** link you need, just add an external link. If you need an anchor and that anchor doesn't exist in every single url of your site, there is definitively a thing you should *not* do: adding just the anchor to the href attribute.

Comment: I believe you completely misunderstood my problem.

Comment: Of course, not. I tried all the links and it works as I understood. Good luck :)